# how to get cell background color of excel using C#?

Tags: c#, excel

I want to retrieve the background color of cell of excel using c# but I just can't find a way to do it

1. which library shall I use ? [`microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.aspx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.aspx) or [`microsoft.office.interop.excel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel(v=vs.140).aspx) ? what's the differents?
2. I have tried following code but get no luck:

   ```
   using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       ofd.Filter = "xlsx|*.xlsx|xls|*.xls";

       if(ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
       {
           textBox2.Text = ofd.FileName;
           Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
           Excel.Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(textBox2.Text);
           Excel.Worksheet ws = wb.Sheets[1];
           Excel.Range xlRange = ws.Cells[0, 0];
           Debug.WriteLine("===" + xlRange.Interior.Color);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I think the real issue here is that the sample code uses zero-based indexing for row and column (i.e., ws.Cells[0,0]). Had you looked at row 1, column A/1 (i.e., ws.Cells[1,1], then the call to Range.Interior.Color would have returned a double as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nice lib called EPPlus, that makes your relationships with excel much easier. You can find it on NuGet.
So use this code to get color:

`var x = sheet.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor;`

And this to set color:

`sheet.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex].Style.Fill.SetCellsColor( Color.Yellow );`

Answer (score 2):

Easiest solution what-so-ever :

```
 private void Get_Colors()
  {
      Excel.Workbook excel = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
      Excel.Worksheet sheet = null;
      Excel.Range ran = sheet.UsedRange;
      for (int x = 1; x <= ran.Rows.Count; x++)
      {
          for (int y = 1; y <= ran.Columns.Count; y++)
          {
              string CellColor = sheet.Cells[x, y].Interior.Color.ToString(); //Here I go double value which is converted to string.
              if (sheet.Cells[x, y].Value != null && (CellColor == Color.Transparent.ToArgb().ToString() || **CellColor == Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbGold.GetHashCode().ToString()**))
              {
                  sheet.Cells[x, y].Interior.Color = Color.Transparent;
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: But I tried, there is no `ran.Rows.Count` in `Excel.Range ran`

Comment: are u missing any reference ?

Comment: I am using `using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;` to include the lib

Comment: @HéctorManuelMartinezDurán,man , how did u become my fan ?!!! what did i do so great man ?!!

Comment: @zackraiyan I'm not your fan, I only give value to your effort

Comment: @zackraiyan What happens is that I close the tab of fb to go to lunch ;-)

Comment: knock me when u are back

Comment: @zackraiyan I'm back

Comment: @zackraiyan go to fb

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer that uses [closed.xml](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML). It's open-source and works with modern Excel sheets.

```
IXLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook("C:\File_path_to_excel_file"); // Replace with your file path
IXLWorksheet ws = wb.Worksheet("SheetName") // Put your sheet name here
int backgroundColor = ws.Cell(rowIndex, colIndex).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Color.ToArgb(); // Gives the Argb values for the cell's background. Replace rowIndex and colIndex with the index numbers of the cell you want to check
```

Typically an uncolored cell's Argb color is 16777215.

Answer (score 1):

That's as simple as following:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
var cellColor  = sheet.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor;
```